# How to store a certain mouse position to use as an original point

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I am currently working on a code to connect ellipses with lines. I have been able to connect each ellipse with the previous. However, i cannot connect the last ellipse and the original (first) ellipse.
I would like to create an array that will

The Ellipses are drawn with the centre being the co-ordinates of where the mouse was clicked.

(Using Processing to code this program)

PS: sorry for bad formatting on the question, this is my first time asking a query.

I have researched on how to use arrays but it is still a bit confusing to me and thus i am using single integers for each point at the moment.

```java
//SET GLOBAL VARIABLES
final int N_PARTITIONS = 10;
int PrevX = -1;
int PrevY = -1;
int count = 0;
int gridx = 0;
int gridy = 0;
int OriginalX = mouseX;
int OriginalY = mouseY;

//CREATING WINDOW SIZE
void setup() {
    size(600, 360);
    surface.setResizable(true);
}

void draw() { 

}

//DRAWING ELLIPSE AND CONNECTING LINES
void mouseClicked() {
    count++;
    CallEllipse();
    if (PrevX != -1) {
        line(PrevX, PrevY, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    if (count >= 3) {
        line(OriginalX, OriginalY, PrevX, PrevY);
    }
    PrevX = mouseX;
    PrevY = mouseY;
}

void CallEllipse() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, N_PARTITIONS, N_PARTITIONS);
}
```

[image]

this is the result of the coding. I am not sure why the line is coming from the top left corner.

Comment: can you try to set only those to:        `int PrevX = 100;
            int PrevY = 100;` as default value

Comment: i have tried changing the values for PrevX and PrevY to 100 as you suggested but the results are about the same, except this time the original ellipse doesnt draw. :(

Comment: Can you try to set the other variables to default value 100, so for: `OriginalX, OriginalY, gridX` ..etc

Comment: good news is, the line no longer connects from the top left corner. Bad news is, it comes out like this https://gyazo.com/9591e2d0fcc8bc83b30c224677f5bd85

Comment: Good - so it seems like the first point that is registered in the list  comes from the Default values - Please do not add the default values in the list, but your first Mouse Click on any point in the screen

Comment: is there a way i would be able to store the original mouse click position?

Comment: Look at my answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

try to Add this code in the `mouseClicked()` method:

```
void mouseClicked() {
     if(count == 0) {
        OriginalX= mouseX;
        OriginalY=mouseY;
     }
      count++;
              CallEllipse();
             if (PrevX != -1) {
                 line(PrevX, PrevY, mouseX, mouseY);
             }
             if (count >= 3) {
               line(OriginalX, OriginalY, mouseX, mouseY);
             }
      PrevX = mouseX;
      PrevY = mouseY;
    }
```

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! it is much appreciated

Comment: Did it work? mark the question as answered if it worked :)

Comment: @UwUvibes you have to Set back the Values to 0 as they were

Comment: @FlamurMuji You should edit the code to reflect the change (set back the value to zero) so future readers won't have to dig in the comments.

Comment: @laancelot there is no other code change required as that I wrote in my answer, I was elaborating with UwUvibes about the behaviour in case of changing the default values he defined :)

Comment: @FlamurMuji No worries then. I though it was weird to draw all the ellipsis from the same, initial point.

Comment: @FlamurMuji it semi-worked. The original point now does link to last point. I just need to figure out how to remove the previous connected line.

https://gyazo.com/44ca64db6441a0f148a91654177c9028

this is the result. Once again, thank you for your help

Comment: @UwUvibes I updated my code I added `&& count <3` check code that I wrote in answer above

Comment: Hi, thank you for the update. However, the update snippet returns this.
https://gyazo.com/78ace814aae577f1cb9d2fc2f30f560a

i think in order to remove the previous line, i'm going to have to draw the background every frame and then redraw all the points.

and have each point in an array.